# Special Connection between two AWS-Regions?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Is there a "special" connection (faster than normal) between the regions of AWS?

> Data transferred between AWS services in different regions will be charged as Internet Data Transfer on both sides of the transfer http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/#dataXferPricing

Comment: What do you mean by ”special”?

Comment: i mean if this connection is extra fast.

Answer (score 4):

All Amazon regions have ridiculously high connectivity to the various public Internet network providers, so connectivity between region A and region B is sure to be far better than going from region A to you to region B.

Amazon optimizes the network connection parameters between EC2 instances and CloudFront edge nodes, so they might also do similar work between EC2 regions.

Note that the network traffic between EC2 regions is not "internal" to Amazon and should be considered untrusted.  Make sure you encrypt any sensitive network traffic between regions.  In fact, Amazon recommends encrypting sensitive network traffic within an EC2 region even though they own the whole thing and take steps to keep it protected and private for you.

Answer (score 3):

There is a private network in each region, spanning all availability zones, **so there is no "special / extra fast way" to connect between two (or more) regions without paying Transfer IN/OUT.**

If you need faster transfer between different regions you may want to take a look at [CloudOpt](http://www.cloudopt.com/home).